# How to teleport every player to a different location?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I’m working on a Minecraft map. My plan is to teleport everybody (at the "event") to a different location.

So the problem is that I cannot do:

```
/minecraft:tp @a[team=event] ~ ~ ~
```

because it would teleport everybody to the same location.

So is there a way to teleport for example using:

```
event.member1 to 10 10 10
```

but also teleport `event.member2` to `20`, `20`, `20`?

Comment: Is the number of players/teams capped or should it work with any amount? `spreadplayers` would work with any amount, but the exact positions are random. If you only have e.g. 4 teams, you could hard-code the positions

Comment: I was about to suggest what @IceFreez3r just mentioned - [`spreadplayers`](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Commands/spreadplayers) should do the job nicely - as long as you're fine with the positions being randomized. It shouldn't be an issue if plan to teleport players into a hub or arena of sorts, where they can move around (you can set the center and the max distance from it), but won't work if you want to teleport players onto, say, pillars.